# How to change visibility of layer in custom style with Mapbox JS GL?

Tags: mapbox

I am a beginner in mapbox JS GL. I am looking for a way to give the user the opportunity to change visibility of layer in mapbox on button click.
In MapBox studio I add to Basic style  visible layer "regions". I tried to do so :

```
<script> ...
var mapp = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map',
style: 'mapbox://styles/terentev/ck2so0c4h1q5x1cqow0aj9nh8',
center: [34.047, 63.779],
zoom: 5.41
});
mapp.setLayoutProperty('regions','visibility','none');
```

But the layer does not disappear.

And when I try get layers from style:

```
var v = mapp.getStyle().layers;
```

I can't. How to do it right?
Thanks in advance!

---

This is layer 'regions', added to Basic style :
[layer 'regions' in mapbox studion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XR2sL.jpg)
I tried like this:

```
var v = mapp.getLayoutProperty('regions', 'visibility');
 alert('visibility '+ v );
 mapp.setLayoutProperty('country-label','visibility','visible');
 v = mapp.getLayoutProperty('regions', 'visibility');
 alert('visibility '+ v );
```

On first alert I get  "visibility undefined"
but there is no  result on second alert at all

Comment: The code looks okay. Just make sure your style has the layer "regions".

Comment: Any console errors?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var mapp = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map',
style: 'mapbox://styles/terentev/ck2so0c4h1q5x1cqow0aj9nh8',
center: [34.047, 63.779],
zoom: 5.41
});

mapp.on('load', () => {
     mapp.setLayoutProperty('regions','visibility','none');
})
```

It just looks like you're invoking `setLayoutProperty` before the map has properly loaded